# Long/Lat to World Tile: y value always NaN

Tags: c#

I am attempting to calculate a world to tile position using an algorithm found [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#C.23)

**My Problem:** when I run the function with a valid long, lat coordinate the y value is always NAN. What is going wrong?

The long, lat coord is: -33.752000f, 151.239000f which is a valid location in Australia.

Do you know whats going wrong?

```
static public Vector2 WorldToTilePos(double lon, double lat, int zoom)
{
    Vector2 p = new Vector2();
    p.x = (float)((lon + 180.0) / 360.0 * (1 << zoom));
    p.y = (float)((1.0 - Math.Log(Math.Tan(lat * Math.PI / 180.0) + 
        1.0 / Math.Cos(lat * Math.PI / 180.0)) / Math.PI) / 2.0 * (1 << zoom));
    Debug.Log (String.Format ("p.y: {0}, lat: {1}", p.y, lat));
    // Always outputs: "p.y: NaN, lat: 151.238998413086"

    return p;
}

// Usuage
Vector2 pos = WorldToTilePos(-33.752000f, 151.239000f, 18);
```

Comment: `Math.Log` is being called with a negative number, which gives you the `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from `Math.Log` being called with a negative number, which gives you the `NaN`. The problem is that `lat` and `long` don't have valid values. From the [site you link](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Derivation_of_tile_names):

```
- x = lon
- y = arsinh(lat) = log[tan(lat) + sec(lat)]
  (lat and lon are in radians)
```

**EDIT:** If I understand it right, I think you're giving `lon` and `lat` in reverse order. Isn't it `WorldToTilePos(151.239000f,-33.752000f, 18)`?

Comment: @JakeM so it was the order?

Comment: no the order was/is correct. it was I was passing degrees when I should have been passing radians.

Answer (score 0):

Input value for the `Math.Log` cannot be less that 0. So

```
Math.Log(x) = NaN   // for x<0
```